# Проблема с часовыми поясами в Django

Tags: django, время

После форматирования даты в Django, а именно:

```
date_pub.strftime('%H')
```

Django выдаёт не тот час(19, а должен быть 22), даже с указанным часовым поясом в 
**settting.py:**

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

Как можно это исправить?

**(Форматируется дата объекта модели в models.py)**

Comment: А на сервере какое время? Правильное? Если нет, то настройте сначала на нём.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pytz
local_time_zone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
local_time_zone.strftime('%H')
```

как-то так....

Comment: К чему это? Проблем с получением текущего времени нету. Проблема с часовым поясом поля в модели.

Comment: тогда проблема с БД - как она сохраняет https://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/i18n/timezones.html

Comment: from django.utils import timezone
timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) что показывает?

Comment: Ничего не показывает.

Comment: во как можно: привязаться к локальному времени TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

Comment: Видимо c TZ какая-то проблема и привязаться к часовому поясу вручную. Чуваку с Аляски такой ход помог - пишут

Answer (score 0):

100% серверное время. Проверьте USE_L10N в settings.py, должен быть True.

Comment: У меня стоит True

Comment: pytz ставьте. Пакет не обязательный, но рекомендованный

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем никак, то принудительно пакетом `pytz`:

```
python3 -m pip install pytz
```